# Make Laravel 8 slug variable case insensitive

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, routes, controller

I have dynamic URL structure, with the following pages table, where page URL is set as page type.
I have Apache server, where URLs are case-sensitive. I want to force route variable to lowercase in case user types in uppercase URL or throw 404 error.

Currently it shows ***View [About] not found*** when URLs are typed in uppercase. How can I force route variable to lowercase or throw Fail error when View/Directory not found?

[image: View not found]

**Page Table**

```
id |     name      |     type     | slug
1  |     About     |      about   | about
2  |    Contact    |    contact   | contact-us
3  | Events & Blog | event_blog | events-blog
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/{page}', 'Controller@page')->name('view_page')->where(['page' => Str::lower('[\w\d\-]+(.*)')]);
```

**Controller**

```
public function page($page)
{
  $page = Page::where('slug' => $page)->firstOrFail();
  return  view($page,  compact('page'));
}
```

I have `about`, `contact`, `event_blog` directories in resources folder, which is working correctly for lowercase URLs, its showing error for uppercase URLs.

Comment: Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php ??

Answer (score 1):

You're geeting this error not from the **model** or **database**, you geeting the error for this line `view($page,  compact('page'));`, because the `****.blade.php` file is not there.
You can change this to :

```
return  view(strtolower($page),  compact('page'));
```

Alternatively,  you can use `whereRaw()` clause to check case sensitive character on your database :

```
Page::whereRaw('BINARY slug=?', $page)->firstOrFail();
```

Or,

```
Page::where(DB::raw('BINARY slug'), $page)->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: Forcing View to lowercase Str::lower($page) works but Str::lower check for 'slug' doesn't work. It should throw Fail when user-input slug isn't lowercase. How to throw error when URL is not lowercase?

Comment: @deep `strtolower` methd on model query will not work, cause laravel  model where() clause is not case sensitive, in this case you need to use whereRaw() or DB::raw, I already mentioned that on my answer

Comment: DB::raw() seems working. It's said, raw is vulnerable to SQL injection. How can I use whereRaw for multiple conditions like `Page::whereRaw(['BINARY slug=?'=> $page, ['status'=>true])->firstOrFail();`. Currently shows `Array to String conversion.`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, maybe **Str::lower() / strtolower()** will help you to solve the problem.

```
$page = Page::where('slug' => \Illuminate\Support\Str::lower($page))->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: Str::lower check for 'slug' doesn't work. It should throw Fail when user-input slug isn't lowercase, but does not. How to throw error when URL is not lowercase?

Comment: Did you mean in web.php?
If you want to reject the request when slug is non-lowercase, your route should be like this:  ->where(['page' => '[a-z0-9\-]+']);